# Getting erorr Cannot POST /undefined/signup

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can sign up a user via postman. But when I use my app I am getting that error. My signup method is ok. But my fetch address is not good. here is method.

```
export const signup = user => {
return fetch(`${API}/signup`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(user)
})
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
};

 const API = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;
```

Comment: `process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL` is undefined double check your env variables (if you're using something like `dotenv` to manage them you will allso need to restart your app)

Comment: I am using dotenv.

Comment: I created file .env in the root directory of  the client folder  added REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:8000/api and it started to work.